# Como mudar a mensagem "O aplicativo x parou de funcionar" no Android?

Tags: android

Eu precisava mudar este texto do meu aplicativo, alguém sabe como? dependendo do modelo do smartphone/tablet a mensagem vem diferente. Agradeço desde já.

Answer (score 4):

Daniel,

Desculpe apontar isto, mas jamais jogue uma exception pura para o usuário. Essa mensagem está acontecendo porque justamente está entrando em algum catch e você está fazendo algo como ex.printStackTrace() ou porque está ocorrendo uma exceção não tratada.

Trate a exceção, exibindo algo mais amigável como um AlertDialog ou um Toast. Se não for impeditiva a situação, não use diálogos.

**Esta é uma mensagem padrão de ANR (Application Not Responding) da qual você não consegue mudar o formato**.

Espero ter ajudado.